# Does 'I certainly will not apologize for doing good journalism' make sense?

Tags: word-usage

I recently watched an interview with a terrible journalist and she said the line:

> I certainly will not apologize for doing good journalism

I'm specifically interested in

> doing good journalism

Does that make sense? It just doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: It could've been worse. She could've said "... giving good journalism". As it stands, the phrase is jingoistic jargon (or jargonistic jingo). Just saying "I will not apologize for good journalism" covers the same territory without the jargon.

Comment: Perfectly fine English. Do state which verb you think he should have used instead. What other options do we even have? You have to be specific what it is you think is wrong, why you think so, what alternatives you are considering, and why exactly they are any better. Otherwise the question is rather pointless. If you just say "*I have a red car* doesn't sound correct to me" and leave it at that, then people *will* fall over themselves finding all kinds of problems with it. You will learn that every single word in it is in the wrong place, spelled incorrectly, and generally not even English.

Comment: @JEL Why's it jingoistic old bean? It doesn't seem to be overly patriotic to me ...

Comment: @RegDwigнt yeah not really arsed with all that. JEL's comment and deadret's answer were perfectly helpful, so they go the jist of what I was asking. Crisis averted.

Comment: @Araucaria I intended the older 'sonorous gibberish' sense, without neglecting a slantwise glance at the persistent chauvinism (devotion to whichever cause will pay the most in this case) of the speaker. All fairly obscure I suppose, but I long ago gave up expecting all or even most of the layers and nuances of my meanings to be taken, and so indulge myself in the depths without much regard for others. Apologies, because you seem to have been misled. To paraphrase T.S. Eliot, "Do I amuse myself? So I amuse myself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [headline](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/washington-post-reporter-wesley-lowery_55c92866e4b0f1cbf1e61822) from yesterday:

> Huffington Post, Washington Post Reporters Charged For **Doing**
>   **Journalism** In Ferguson

Journalism is understood (at least by its practitioners) as incorporating many hands-on activities -- investigating, interviewing, fact-checking, research, writing, editing, etc. -- which makes the verb "to do" apposite.